# How to get FB Graph API Business Rating

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have recently started using Facebook's Graph API.  I was wondering is there a way I can get just the overall rating of a business that I am not the owner of the page of.  I am aware that there is a ratings edge that allows you to pull all reviews if you have a page-access token but I do not have this and do not need that detailed information.  I do not see any fields in the "page" documentation and do not want to resort to scraping.  This will be used in an app to compare businesses.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to get ratings/reviews of a Page you don´t own. As you found out yourself, you do need a Page Token, and you don´t get one if your user does not belong to any Page role. There is no way to get the ratings/review in that case, and scraping is not allowed: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php